# Element values shifting and changing before transition with react-transition-group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-transition-group

I noticed this behavior while using the `react-transition-group` package in a gatsby project I'm working on. I have a list of "tags" that are added to an active list as they are picked from another master list. Clicking a tag from the master list adds it to the active list, and clicking a tag from the active list removes it. Pretty much how you would expect something like this to work.

The transition *in* works just fine, but when transitioning *out* the tags re-organize themselves in a strange way. We have five tags with the following values:

- Dairy Free
- Party Food
- Family Sized
- Low Cholesterol
- Low Sodium

If you click the `Family Sized` tag to remove it, the following occurs:

1. `Family Sized` disappears instantly
2. `Low Cholesterol` and `Low Sodium` shift instantly to the left
3. The last tag changes to `Low Sodium` instantly
4. The last tag, now with the value of `Low Sodium` transitions out

The expected behavior is that the `Family Sized` tag transitions out from where it is in the middle of the group. I should note that it works fine if you remove the *last* tag from the active list, this only happens when removing a tag from any other position.

Here is a [slowed-down GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLYQc.jpg) of the transition and here is my code:

```
<TransitionGroup className='tag-container'>
  {filter.map((tag, index) => {
    return (
      <CSSTransition key={index} timeout={250} classNames={`tag`}>
        <TagButton value={tag} onClick={onClickFunction} className={`${screenStyle} active`}>{tag}</TagButton>
      </CSSTransition>
    )
  })}
</TransitionGroup>
```

- `filter` is an array destructured from the component's state.
- There is a `<StaticQuery>` from `gatsby` used in the same `render()` method of the component if that matters.
- The `<TagButton>` is a styled component from `styled-components` package, not a separately imported component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding specific identifier in your array and setting key of each element to each identifier in map method will solve your problem.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./styles.css";
import uuid from "uuid";

function App() {
  const [items, setitems] = React.useState([
    { id: uuid(), name: "Dairy Free" },
    { id: uuid(), name: "Party Food" },
    { id: uuid(), name: "Family Sized" },
    { id: uuid(), name: "Low Cholesterol" },
    { id: uuid(), name: "Low Sodium" }
  ]);
  const removeitem = item => {
    setitems(items.filter(itemname => itemname.id !== item));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TransitionGroup className="todo-list">
        {items.map(data => (
          <CSSTransition timeout={500} classNames="item" key={data.id}>
            <Button className="m-2" onClick={() => removeitem(data.id)}>
              {data.name}
            </Button>
          </CSSTransition>
        ))}
      </TransitionGroup>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

This problem is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35979761), so please checkout to understand this strange behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

For future reference if anyone comes across this. The issue was with how the `key` value was being passed to the tags.

My code was mapping through the `filter` array and assigning the `index` of each value as the child components' keys. This means they are keyed as 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. When a tag is removed from the `filter` array and the page re-renders, the indexes are re-applied in whatever order the array is in, which means that they all shift instead of the one that was removed being "plucked out" from wherever it was.

The solution was to use a unique key that doesn't rely on the array's index values at all. Here is what I updated to:

```
<TransitionGroup className='tag-container'>
  {filter.map((tag) => {
    return (
      <CSSTransition key={`active_${tag}`} timeout={250} classNames={`tag`}>
        <TagButton value={tag} onClick={onClickFunction} className={`${screenStyle} active`}>{tag}</TagButton>
      </CSSTransition>
    )
  })}
</TransitionGroup>
```