# React Native receving new props, componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm struggling with some updates on my Component. I know I **shouldn't** set props inside the states. However, I had to do this to make my component update properly:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      doctor: nextProps.data.name,
      address: nextProps.data.address 
    })
}
```

Is there a better way to do that? Is a best approach if I do this ->

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.props.data.name = nextProps.data.name;
        this.props.data.name = nextProps.data.address;
     })
 }
```

I was trying to use the shouldComponentUpdate:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextProps.id !== this.props.id;
}
```

but I didn't work quite well for me.c

Comment: don't change props from within the component, that's what state is for...

Comment: Why do you need to bring your props into state? Are you mutating them? React re renders any component when a prop that is being used in that component is changed!

Comment: @Idiot211, the app has ListView where it stores some favourites items, to unfavourite the item I do trough another component (e.g details-item), when I come back to the ListView the item I unfavourited still there and another item disappeared. When I use componentWillReceiveProps and update the states with new props, it works. I hope it does make sense.

Comment: @Gabriel Lopes -- Interesting. I can see what you mean. But I just feel like there's a larger underlying issue. If your list view has a list of items and they render item views. Surely it would make sense to bubble the unfavourite event up to the list component and allow the list component to mutate the list which would then re-render all the items? -- That's just my thought. -- I do understand what you're trying to do. It just seems convoluted to me.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment, you mention:

> when I come back to the ListView the item I unfavourited still there
>   and another item disappeared

This looks like a problem in a completely different area. My guess would be that you are using the wrong `key` in a list. Probably an index. Keys should always be unique to the item you are displaying, and index is not (e.g. the first item is always index 0, and when you rearrange the list, or delete the first item, another item will have index 0, and react does not work well then.) [Further explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705046/5358807).

About "updating the component properly":

- If you pass in new props, react automatically re-renders with the new props. You do not need to do anything in `componentWillReceiveProps` for this.
- `componentWillReceiveProps` is for updating state, based on comparing OLD and NEW props. (e.g. if you want to display whether number of likes in a prop has gone up or down)
- `shouldComponentUpdate` is optional. Main purpose is to increase performance *without any functional change to the workings of your component*: to tell react early on that the component is unchanged. I would advise not to include `shouldComponentUpdate` as long as your component does not yet work as intended.

Comment: I see, I will have a look at the components again, maybe I'm looking at the wrong place, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess here. As I perceive it, you experience issues properly implementing `shouldComponentUpdate`. I believe you try comparing `nextProps.data` objects and always have **not equal** result, even though the data within is equal. The reason for it is that the object references to `data` objects are different. In order to overcome that issue, you should be doing a deep comparison, similar to [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s `_.isEqual` instead.

As mentioned in comments, updating nextProps in `componentWillReceiveProps` is a horrendous idea.

Comment: thanks, I see, thanks I will have a look, probably it's something silly like usual, I'll also take a look at lodash.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I am stuck on a similar issue. I am trying to setState inside componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: best way to know if the props changed is with componentDidUpdate(props){..update state }